# What's the API name of system permissions?

Tags: metadata-api

I am adding the system permissions 'Manage Public List Views' and 'Create and Customize List Views' to a permission set via the Metadata API. The problem is I can't find their exact API name:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>CreateCustomizeListViews</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManagePublicListViews</name>
</userPermissions>
```

... this is what I have which seems right, but I want to be absolutely sure. Are you supposed to have the 'and' in there? Previously there was a permission here that read:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>CreateCustomizeFilters</name>
</userPermissions>
```

... so that's why I named 'Create Customize List Views' that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Metadata API sometimes have different API names than the one shown on the UI.

Manage Public List Views permission is called as "**EditPublicFilters**" and Create and Customize List Views is called as "**CreateCustomizeFilters**"

So your user permission will be.

```
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateCustomizeFilters</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditPublicFilters</name>
    </userPermissions>
```

Comment: This is the core base of Salesforce which was designed in 2000's , probably when they designed they didnt want to name it as "List View"  and keep it as Filter. SF Over the years they renamed the Lable to ListView but kept the API name as same for backward compatibility,

Answer (score 8):

The best place to check for it is the workbench.

[image]

Reference: [API Names of System and App Permissions?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BdJIAU)

Comment: Its weird, The one I pulled via Ant has value "CreateCustomizeFilters" where as from the API it says `PermissionsCreateCustomizeFilters` , Unless `Permissions` is a prefix

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I guess that might be it!

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yes, the workbench returns the "SOAP" version of the Profile, which is where the "Permissions" prefix comes from. And it's in the docs for the Profile sobject in the SOAP API, too.

Comment: @sfdcfox got it. Now makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Hover over the checkbox of a permission to see it's metadata name

[image]

Comment: That's cool. Thanks @Maciej